How to use class member variables inside Junit-Mockito tests
class MyClass {
    MyErrorServiceList myErrorServiceList; // myErrorServiceList is initialized by some complex method calls
    
    public boolean processErrorServiceList() {
        if (CollectionUtils.NotEmplty(myErrorServiceList)) {
            // do something
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false;
        }
    }
}

How can I pass myErrorServiceList when calling processErrorServiceList() so that both branches of the code are covered by a test case?

What did you try that didn't work?

Have you tried a setter, even if you are using it only internally?

How can I write junit test case that bypass (CollectionUtils.NotEmplty(myErrorServiceList)) , currently I am using , when( (CollectionUtils.NotEmplty(any())).thenreturn(true), but this not works and throwing Mockito exception

a) redesign your class to be testable b) move method out of class and make public static, so it can be tested independent of class for any kind of list c) use reflection to assign the field d) call your complex methods and have your list initialized. And honestly, I wouldn't test that method separately, it looks like a private implementation detail and should be covered by other tests that perform actual validation of important business logic.

use ReflectionTestUtils.setField method

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
